# Copy files using puppet with relative path

Tags: puppet

I am trying to write code with puppet and vagrant, and am unable to find how to copy a file from the directory containing the manifest to the target server.

In ansible I used this:

```
- name: Copy public key
  copy:   
    src: ./myKey
    dest: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I would like to do something like this with puppet

```
- file { 'myKey':
  path    => '/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys',
  ensure  => file,
  source  => ./myKey }
```

I understand how to make this work using absolute path, but would like to use relative path here as my script will be pulled down with a git clone and run on another machine that will have different directory setups.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.1", auto_config: true
 config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.2-64-puppet-enterprise"
 config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifest_file = "srv_site.pp"
 end
end
```

Comment: Master or no master?

Comment: I'm using vagrant to bring it up so I presume master?  I am using this:

    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.provision "puppet" 
    end

Would I be better off using this? puppet.module_path = "./" or is that going to look in the modules folder still?  

Sorry if this is obvious through testing, I will test this out on Monday.  

With a puppet -apply I know there is the -module option to specify but I don't know how to do that with vagrant.

Comment: Please post the Puppet provisioning part of the Vagrantfile to let us know the setup.

Comment: Added the vagrantfile

Comment: What does your module's directory structure look like?

Comment: I have not touched that yet.  Am still reading up on it, but I thought (possibly incorrectly?) that moving files into the module directory would require that copying the project onto someone else's machine would also require moving files into that machine's module directory - which is what I was trying to avoid by using the ./<filename> for the file source.

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy a file in puppet you need to put the file in the module path under files. So if your module is named mymodule the file should go here:

```
./mymodule/files/mykey
```

and in the module the file is copied by

```
 file { 'mykey':
    ensure => file,
    path   => '/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys',
    source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/mykey"
  }
```

you cannot point source to a different place on the puppet master, unless you set up a file server mount point on the pupper master see https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/file_serving.html.
but the source can point to other places see https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/types/file.html#file-attribute-source.